# HTML and JavaScript to show text on select change

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so, I got a list, and I want to show some text when the user SELECTS an option from the dropdown, I figured how to make for it for one option but for some reason doesn't work in groups so well.

```
<select id="mySelect" name="values">
<option value=0>0</option>
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
</select>
```

I intend to "print" some determined text as each option is selected, thanks!

(sorry for any grammar errors, spanish speaker here)

Comment: Please share the code that you tried.

Comment: Yes You can do it so. You can get help from Jquery. You can prefer this link http://jqueryui.com/show/

Comment: Where are you trying to show the text? Also, are you using library like jquery?

Comment: Does your html document type permit attribute values without quotes value=0 not value="0" ? Do we want the value to appear outside the select control? If so, do we have a form submit action or a handler for an event that occurs when an option gets selected, such as a JavaScript function attached to onchange?

Comment: I was trying this: http://jsbin.com/ijogi/1/edit It works but only with one select, I want to "print" different texts on each selection, I changed the var names but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showstuff(element){ 
    document.getElementById("una").style.display = element=="una"?"block":"none"; 
    document.getElementById("dos").style.display = element=="dos"?"block":"none"; 
    document.getElementById("tres").style.display = element=="tres"?"block":"none"; 
    document.getElementById("cuatro").style.display = element=="cuatro"?"block":"none"; 
    document.getElementById("cinco").style.display = element=="cinco"?"block":"none"; 
    document.getElementById("seis").style.display = element=="seis"?"block":"none"; 
    document.getElementById("siete").style.display = element=="siete"?"block":"none"; 
    document.getElementById("ocho").style.display = element=="ocho"?"block":"none"; 
    document.getElementById("nueve").style.display = element=="nueve"?"block":"none"; 
    document.getElementById("diez").style.display = element=="diez"?"block":"none";     
    } 
</script> 

<select name="type" onchange="showstuff(this.value);"> 
          <option value="una" selected>1</option> 
          <option value="dos">2</option> 
          <option value="tres">3</option> 
          <option value="cuatro">4</option> 
          <option value="cinco">5</option> 
          <option value="seis">6</option> 
          <option value="siete">7</option> 
          <option value="ocho">8</option> 
          <option value="nueve">9</option> 
         <option value="diez">10</option> 
</select> 
<div id="uno" style="display:none;">uno</div> 
<div id="dos" style="display:none;">dos</div> 
<div id="tres" style="display:none;">tres</div> 
<div id="cuatro" style="display:none;">cuatro</div> 
<div id="cinco" style="display:none;">cinco</div> 
<div id="seis" style="display:none;">seis</div> 
<div id="siete" style="display:none;">siete</div> 
<div id="ocho" style="display:none;">ocho</div> 
<div id="nueve" style="display:none;">nueve</div> 
<div id="diez" style="display:none;">diez</div>
```

Thanks every one :)